# C: Replace bit in an int at specific position using bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, mask, unsigned-integer

I have a C program below that will replace a specified bit of a number from another number.
Ex:

```
Let first no whose bit is to be replaced is:
7 //0000 0111

Second no from whom bit is to be replaced
8 //0000 1000

Specified position: 3 (0-indxed)

Converted number will be 15
```

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int first,second,pos;

  printf("enter first & second no:\n");
  scanf("%d %d",&first,&second);

  printf("enter specified position(0-indexed)\n");
  scanf("%d",&pos);

  //collect corresponding bit of second no
  int temp=(second>>pos)&1;

  //if bit at specified position is 1
    if(temp==1){
      temp=temp<<pos;
      first|=temp;
      }
     else{ //if bit at specified position is 0
      int flag=255;//FF, all bit set to 1(considering 8 bit numbers)
      temp=1<<pos;
      //this set only the specified position bit 0 others 1
      flag=flag^temp;
      first&=flag;
     }

printf("converted no %d\n",first);

return 0;
```

}

Thankfully this all works fine for 8 bit integers. My issue is that I need the program to work up to 32 bit ints (Positive ints smaller than 3 billion). Whenever I use bigger numbers like 2 billion it doesn't output the correct converted number. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the smallest number for which it fails? What is the size of int in your environment?

Comment: You have a problem with numbers wider than 8 bit and a comment `(considering 8 bit numbers)`. There seems to be a connection, don't you think?

Comment: "How can I fix this issue?" --> Start by using 32-bit unsigned objects.

Comment: You might like to learn the complement operator `~`. It inverts all bits of its (integer) operand.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
int flag = 255;   //FF, all bit set to 1 (considering 8 bit numbers)
```

Makes your code unable to deal with number higher than 255, which require more than 8 bit to be stored.

Considering a 32-bit `int` (common in general purpose architectures) and a two's complement representation (not mandated by the standard, but quite prevalent), you could use a function like the following ([here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o3rl99tJ22Pxaujj), an example of usage):

```
int copy_bit(int dest, int source, int pos)
{    
    assert(0 <= pos  &&  pos < (int)(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)));

    // Calculate the bit mask
    unsigned mask = 1u << pos;

    // Clear the bit in the destination
    unsigned tmp = (unsigned)dest & ~mask;

    // Set the bit from the source
    tmp |= (unsigned)source & mask;

    return (int)tmp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is because you are using int. The 32 signed int has max value: 2^31 -1 
You should use unsigned int to solve your problem. Unsigned 32 bit int has max value: 2^32.
Then you can simply bit flipping logic like this:

```
first = first & ((0x1u<<pos) & second)
```

Comment: I believe there is another problem in OPs code. Did you try whether it works if you only change the data type? I doubt it.

Comment: correct. I didnt check the else part, let me edit the answer.

Comment: Max value of 32bit unsignet int is not 2 to the power of 32 (or 2^32, as you represent it).

Comment: "Unsigned 32 bit int has max value: 2^32." needs re-work too.  Off by 1

Comment: `0x1<<pos` is back to `int` math.  Consider `0x1u <<pos`

Comment: Is that the code which is supposed to do the job completly or only in `else` case? I.e. I think your code needs more context.

Comment: That code should solve your question: "replace a specified bit of a number from another number"